# PHP array needs to remove almost identical values, but trim make script freeze

Tags: php

So I have a script that pulls links from web pages and saves them to a array, then removes duplicate links.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($this->doc); //Create instance of DOMXpath() class. --php core--
$elements = $xpath->query("//a[not(@rel='nofollow')]/@href"); //Use $xpath to pull links from page. nofollow links are ignored.
$this_page= array(); //Insure $this_page is set, even if 0 links are found causing a false null on is_null
if (!is_null($elements)) foreach ($elements as $element) $this_page[]= $element->nodeValue; //Create a array of located links from DOMXpath object.

$this_page= array_unique($this_page); //Remove duplacate links.
$url_path= parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH); //Get the path of link to locate file infomation.
if(is_file(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . ltrim($url_path, '/') . "{,.php,.html,.htm}", GLOB_BRACE)[0]))  //Determan the file extension and remove root path.
{
$directories= explode('/', rtrim($path, '/'));
array_pop($directories);
$path= implode('/', $directories);
}
else
{
array_push($this->dead_links, array("page"=>rtrim($path, '/'), "link"=>'test'));
}
clearstatcache(); //Clear catched values.
```

It works almost perfectly, but runs into a issue with similar links, specifically when there is a root relative link and page relative links

example:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/page_one"></a>
<a href="www.mysite.com/page_two"></a>
<a href="page_one"></a>
<a href="page_two"></a>
<a href="/page_two"></a>
```

The resulting array after the entire script runs turns into:

```
$this_page[0]= 'page_one';
$this_page[1]= 'page_two';
$this_page[2]= '/page_two';
```

of course the `$this_page[2]= '/page_two'` is the same as `$this_page[1]= 'page_two'` but `array_unique()` doesn't know that beclause of the `'/'`.

I tried adding a `trim()` in a loop to `$this_page`, but that makes the script freeze, or slow down way too much, I can't tell which. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

When your building the list of anchor urls, try...

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $this_page[]= ltrim($element->nodeValue,"/");
}
```

This trims the name as it builds the list up.

As an alternative, you could ensure that they all start with a '/' and make them consistent that way.

Comment: That didn't make any difference. and I can't ensure anything that comes from the page being searched.

Comment: Interesting as I tried it with your sample data and doing a `print_r($this_page);` just after the `array_unique()` has the version with the `/` removed.

Comment: alright, my bad. I put the code in the wrong spot. but now that I have it right I'm running into the massive slow down/freeze issue again.

Comment: Can you try it without the duplicate (i.e. the `<a href="/page_two"></a>`) see if that still has the problem as this shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: so removing the links without '/' be hind them doesn't change anything. the script is for a site crawler and is slow to begin with. I was able to confirm the script is still running, but I don't understand how simply adding trim() to the array slows it down so drastically. with out it the script runs in about a minute, but with trim() it takes over ten minutes.

Comment: I can't tell what the rest of your script is doing, especially as the code you included about doesn't do anything with `$this_page` once it builds this array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165374/discussion-between-zaper127-and-nigel-ren).